# How to change the caret/cursor size of a UISearchBar in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I know that the caret rect of a UITextView or UITextField can be changed by overriding the caretRectForPosition method, but I can't figure out how to do the same for a UISearchBar.  Is this possible?